# How do I resolve error Call to undefined method assertSessionHasErrors in laravel unit tests?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

Using Laravel 8, I'm running some unit tests, but getting this error on one of my tests:

```
Call to undefined method Tests\Unit\ApplicationTest::assertSessionHasErrors()
```

```php
use Tests\TestCase;
class ApplicationTest extends TestCase {
...
    $applicationRef = Application::inRandomOrder()->pluck('reference')->first();
    $this->post(
        'http://website.test/applications/'.$applicationRef.'/update',
        ['title' => null]
    );

    $this->assertSessionHasErrors('title');
}
```

I've tried all sorts to test form validation, but cant get any to work. any advice would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store the result of `$this->post` in a variable and use that.

```php
$applicationRef = Application::inRandomOrder()->pluck('reference')->first();
$response = $this->post(
    'http://website.test/applications/'.$applicationRef.'/update',
    ['title' => null]
);

$response->assertSessionHasErrors('title');
```

Comment: thanks @matiaslauriti, however, using your example returns the error Session is missing expected key [errors].  Failed asserting that false is true. any thoughts?

Comment: That means your controller is not returning any errors. My code is correct, it is asserting what it should. Can you share your controller ?